# Convert 32/64 bit number to 4/8 character string

Tags: bash

Given that:

```
$ printf "love" | od -td4 -A n
  1702260588
$ printf "lovehate" | od -td8 -A n
  7310575196135911276
```

Is there a concise (ideally without loops, awk, sed, perl or python) way in Bash to convert the numbers `1702260588` and `7310575196135911276` to `love` and `lovehate` respectively?

Comment: A quick aside: `-A` takes a _single_-character option-argument; you probably meant `-A n` (though in practice both GNU and BSD/OSX `od` accept and quietly ignore additional characters, allowing you to get creative; e.g.: `od -td4 -A xoxo`; `od -td4 -A dorky`; `od -td4 -A oho`; `od -td4 -A notsofast`).

Comment: @mklement0: Quite right, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
alpha() {
  (($1)) && printf "\x"$(printf "%02x" $(($1%256)))$(alpha $(($1/256)))"\n"
}

alpha 1702260588
alpha 7310575196135911276
```

Output:

```
love
lovehate
```

Edit: Here's an answer using the `xxd` utility:

```
# The echo is only necessary to get a newline at the end.
echo $(printf "%x" 1702260588 | xxd -r -p | rev)
echo $(printf "%x" 7310575196135911276 | xxd -r -p | rev)
```

Output:

```
love
lovehate
```

Comment: Very cool understanding of these basic tools, but doesn't seem like it would be any more efficient that calling awk. Upvote definitely, but "kids, don't rely on this method at home for large scale processing" ;-)  Good luck to all.

Comment: I agree, but OP asked for no loops, awk, sed, perl or python. For examnple, the only reason I used recursion is because he asked for no loops. It's a bit of a cheat, but I was just trying to answer the question as it was asked.

Comment: ideally without loops, awk, sed, perl or python ... and recursion! :) Actually, I think this is pretty neat, though I was kind of hoping that someone would tell me about a little known utility that can do this easily. Agree with upvote.

Comment: There's a utility called xxd that might be of use.

Comment: You beat me to it! Actually I've been looking at `xxd` but I can't see how it can help here.  It seems to always treat the standard input as a string which is a pain.

Comment: Nicely done; from what I can tell, however, `rev` automatically adds a trailing `\n` (GNU `rev`, BSD/OSX `rev`)  - no need for `echo`.

Comment: @mklement0 It didn't work on my machine. I got `lovelovehate` as the output. I added the `echo` to fix that. You must have a different version of `rev` than I do. Either way, the `echo` is not really important to the solution. It was just to make the output look cleaner.

Comment: @MikeHolt: Agreed, it is a tangent, but now you've piqued my curiousity: what platform, what `rev` implementation / version? To promote good habits I suggest you double-quote the command substitution (`$( ... )`), because, generally speaking, the output will otherwise be subject to globbing and whitespace normalization.

Comment: @mklement0 I'm running Manjaro Linux and `rev -V` reports `rev from util-linux 2.27.1`. I double-checked and it definitely does not add a trailing newline.

Comment: @MikeHolt: Thanks for letting me know. It seems that the behavior changed sometime after util-linux 2.20.1 (the version that Ubuntu 14.04 comes with, for instance) - though I couldn't find anything in the release notes. Arguably, it's a change for the better. I still suggest double-quoting the command substitutions; i.e.: `echo "$(printf "%x" 1702260588 | xxd -r -p | rev)"` and `echo "$(printf "%x" 7310575196135911276 | xxd -r -p | rev)"`